# Redirect htaccess old folder to a new folder with index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need a big help.
My `htaccess` is configured to redirect all `http` content to `https` and this works fine, but is the root content only.

I spent a lot of time researching the web how to redirect the contents of a website with URL not `SSL` to a new `SSL` URL, but the solutions i've found does not work on my scenario.

My .HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

What I want is this.

when the user visits the http://www.example.com/oldfolder/index.php?site=document-name redirect to https://example.com/new-folder/other-folder/index.php?site=document-name

But i found nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.org\/home\/" [R=301,L]
```

Here the redirection will work if someone types `example.org`. The person will be redirected to `example.org/home`. 
To see just click here [cubehub.org](http://cubehub.org)

If you're using Cpanel just go to Redirects(`cPanel >> Home >> Domains >> Redirects`) and set the URL redirection.

Comment: Thanks, I will test.